# Codimension of cusp singularities in the space of 2-jets

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, singularity-theory, invariant-theory, jets

In trying to prove Cerf's theorem about homotopies between Morse-functions I ended up thinking about the following problem.

For $n>2$, $a= (a_{i,j})\in GL(n-2)$, we define the polynomial map $C_a:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^2$
$$C_a(x_1,\dots, x_n) = (x_1,\  x_1 x_2 + \sum_{i,j\geq 3} a_{i,j} x_i x_j)$$
$C$ stands for "cusp".

Let $\mathcal P$ be the space of polynomial maps $\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^2$ of degree at most $2$.  This is a  real vector space of dimension $N = 1+n + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

Define the subset $\Sigma \subset \mathcal P$ as follows: $p\in \Sigma$ if  $\exists A \in GL(n),  B \in GL(2), a \in GL(n-2)$ such that
$$B \circ p \circ (A x) = C_a(x). $$

In other words $\Sigma$ is the union of the orbits of the maps $C_a$ under the action of $GL(n)\times GL(2)$.

> What is the codimension of $\Sigma$ in $\mathcal P$ ? Is there a neat way to see it?

The only thing I can think of is to understand what is trying to compute the dimension of the stabilizer.  This should, I believe, be known as cusp singularities have been extensively studied.

*More about the motivation.*
$C_a$ is related to cusp singularities as follows. In the space of 2-jets $J^2(M,\mathbb R^2)$
we can define a subset $\mathcal C$ consisting of those 2-jets that are conjugated to $C_a$. If a map $f:M\to \mathbb R^2$ has 2-jet $j^2f$ transverse to $\mathcal C$ then $f$ is locally (to a point intersecting $\mathcal C$) modelled like a cusp singularity.
I am trying to understand what is the codimension of $\mathcal C$.

Comment: I'm a little confused about how this relates to Cerf theory.  The cusps are cubics, but your functions are all quadratic.

Comment: @RyanBudney the "cubicness" is due to transversality in the same way as "quadraticness" of a Morse singularity $f:M\to \mathbb R$ is due to transversality with a subset of $J^1(M,\mathbb R)$ specified by polynomials of degree 1 (those with vanishing differential.)
See also the More about the motivation paragraph at the end of the question.

Comment: More formally,
given a  map $f:M\times I \to \mathbb R^2$, and let $\Sigma^{m}(f)\subset M\times I$ be the subset where $df$ has rank 1, suppose this is a smooth curve in $M\times I$, and that at $p\in \Sigma^{m}(f)$ the 2-jet  of $f$, $j^2f$ is equivalent to $C_a$; if  $j^2f$ is transverse to the submanifold  $\mathcal C \subset J^2(M,\mathbb R^2)$ described above then $f$ has a cusp singularity at $p$ (so it has the well known cubic expression in some coordinate system).